# mysql : match against and having query with max

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

> SELECT *,MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean mode)  as
>   relevance FROM `blog` where `active` = 1

The above query returns 5 rows with relevance 2,2,0,0,0

Now I want to select only the rows with maximum relevance.
So it should return only the rows which has 2 as their relevance.

I tried the following query.

> SELECT *,MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean mode)
>   as relevance FROM `blog` where `active` = 1 having
>   relevance=max(MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean
>   mode))

But it returns only one row..

Is there any way to get only that two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean mode) as relevance 
FROM blog 
where active = 1
and MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean mode) = (select max(MATCH(title,text) AGAINST('my home' in boolean mode)) from blog)
```